# SQL server + dynamic query + 'The data types nvarchar and bit are incompatible in the add operator.'

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to join a string of database values but in this statement:

```
SET @sql = ('select' + @var1 + '+' + convert(varchar,@var2) + 
            'from [VoucherType] where [DeletedBy] is null and [AutoID] = 1')
```

I get an error saying

> The data types nvarchar and bit are incompatible in the add
>   operator.

`@var2` which is `[IsBirthdayVoucher]` in my database is a `bit` type but I have already applied `convert(varchar, @var2)` on it. Please kindly advice what I am doing wrong. Thanks.

SPROC:

```
declare @Str as varchar(max) 
declare @var1 as varchar(30)=null
declare @var2 as varchar(30)=null
declare @var3 as varchar(30)=null
declare @var4 as varchar(30)=null
declare @var5 as varchar(30)=null

declare @sql as varchar(355)

set @Str = '[Code][IsBirthdayVoucher][IsReusable]VouT' 

    Set @var1=  (select LEFT(@Str, CHARINDEX(']', @Str)))  
        set @Str = SUBSTRING(@Str, CHARINDEX(']', @Str) + 1, LEN(@Str))     
    Set @var2 =(select LEFT(@Str, CHARINDEX(']', @Str)))
        set @Str = SUBSTRING(@Str, CHARINDEX(']', @Str) + 1, LEN(@Str))         
    Set @var3 =(select LEFT(@Str, CHARINDEX(']', @Str)))  
        set @Str = SUBSTRING(@Str, CHARINDEX(']', @Str) + 1, LEN(@Str))     

    SET @sql = ('select' + @var1 + '+' + convert(varchar,@var2) + 'from [VoucherType] where [DeletedBy] is null and [AutoID] = 1')

          EXEC(@sql)
```

Comment: I think there *should* be a space after `'select'`, i.e. it should be `'select '`. The `[` will act as a delimiter, but in the interests of defensive programming...

Comment: I upvoted against the downvote. I don't understand why there was a downvote, this seems like a reasonable question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're not converting `[IsBirthdayVoucher]` to `VARCHAR`, you're converting `@var2` to `VARCHAR`.

Try:

```
SET @sql = ('Select ' + @var1 + ' + Convert(varchar, ' + @var2 + ') 
             From [VoucherType] 
             Where [DeletedBy] is Null AND [AutoID] = 1')
```

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
SET @sql = ('Select CONCAT(' + @var1 + ',' + @var2 + ') 
             From VoucherType 
             Where DeletedBy is Null and [AutoID] = 1')
```