# Convert Password varchar() to binary datatype in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, casting, binary

I want to take password from **Table 1** to **Table 2**. So I have to convert.

**Table 1:**

- Password(varchar)

**Table 2:**

- Password(binary)

  I am logging here convert varchar to binary.I try this following query,

  ```
   IsNull(''''+cast(wl.password as binary)+'''', 'NULL')+')'
  ```

but no use. It is showing error like,

```
The data types varchar and binary are incompatible in the add operator.
```

give me some suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Try using `convert` function in sql.

Eg.

```
convert(varchar, ' + @password + ')
```

Refer:

[SQL server + dynamic query + 'The data types nvarchar and bit are incompatible in the add operator.'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8455309/sql-server-dynamic-query-the-data-types-nvarchar-and-bit-are-incompatible-i)

Hope its helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Don't cast it to binary before concatenating a string, but within the string, so it get casted when dynamic query is executed.

Something like:

```
ISNULL('cast(''' +wl.password+ ''' as binary)','NULL')
```